# Seeking OpenStreetMap satellite images service beyond Google Maps service?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, satellite

I have come back to a private QGIS project that I designed 3 months ago and I get a message from the Google Map Service like:

> For Deployment Purposes Only

Are there attempts to provide satellite images within the OpenStreetMap database context without Google Maps?

Comment: This is a question for http://help.openstreetmap.org/ and has already been asked and answered there: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/55558/satellite-image-availability and https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/27875/satellite-imagery and https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/7602/satellite-imagery-availability and https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/41270/how-can-i-show-osm-map-as-satellite-view-in-my-application and some more...

Comment: Hi,  scie I've clicked all the provided links with a summary result of 4 times nop! OK yes it is IMO "not only" a openstreetmap question and OSM is great. With the headline "Are there attempts to provide" I mean somesthing, a platfrom of where to collect, process and provide such stuff.

Comment: There are already several other aerial imagery providers apart from Google. And there is [OpenAerialMap](https://openaerialmap.org/).

Comment: OK, thank you. But one question is there platform to place existing data, I'm the owner of LANDSAT 5 and IRS-1C &1D data of western pomerania of the 90ies.

Comment: Can't answer that. Since there isn't much interest in outdated aerial imagery for *most* users you will have a hard time finding a suitable platform, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @scai:

> There are already several other aerial imagery providers apart from
>   Google. And there is [OpenAerialMap](https://openaerialmap.org/).

[OpenAerialMap](https://openaerialmap.org/) is for:

> **The open collection of aerial imagery.**
>
> OpenAerialMap is an open service to provide access to a commons of
>   openly licensed imagery and map layer services. Download or contribute
>   imagery to the growing commons of openly licensed imagery.